# Can Transformers die or get sick from radiation?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

In the 80's G1 episode "Cosmic rust" it is stated that Transformers can get sick from microorganisms that devour Cybertronian metals. Iron Hide from the Bay movie Transformers Dark of the moon is melted by Sentinel Prima's Cosmic rust gun. But this is not through any form of radiation.

My inspiration to this question was watching a series called Chernobyl, and several Transformers visiting Chernobyl in the Bay Transformers Dark of the Moon, where the Autobots find a piece of equipment while being under attack by Decepticon Shockwave. Speaking of Shockwave it has been stated non canon that the explosion at Tunguska in 1908 was caused by him, while he crashed on earth.

Can a Transformer, from whatever generation, get sick or die from radiation?

Comment: https://transformers.fandom.com/wiki/Energon_radiation

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In the Beast Wars story, the sole reason for adopting a beast mode was to protect the Transformers from the high levels of energon radiation present on Earth, which threatened to extinguish their sparks.

In the first episode, Beast Wars 1, after crash landing Megatron has the following conversation with his ship computer:

> Megatron: Tell me there is energon here.
>
> Computer: Confirmed.
>
> Megatorn: Yes, the planet has energon!
>
> Computer: Too much energon. Field readings are off the scale. Continued exposure to robotic forms will result in permanent damage.
>
> Megatron: Then we will create alternate forms based on the most powerful local creatures.

Comment: Can you provide a quote that shows this?

Comment: https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Beast_mode

Comment: https://youtu.be/wLADRGY5ZpE?t=99